# Function defined in setTimeout has access to the outer variables in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, scope, this, settimeout

I know that `this` keyword always refers to the `this` of the current scope, which changes any time you wrap something in `function() { ... }`. My question is, why do I have access to the outer scope variable `x` in the function inside the `setTimeout` function?

```js
var x = 45;

function getRecipe(recipe) {
  x = 35;
  return {
    displayRecipe: function(a) {
      //here we have access to x=35
      setTimeout(function() {
        //why do we have access to x=35 and to recipe here?
        console.log(this.x + a + recipe);
      }, 1500)
    }
  }
}

getRecipe("noodles").displayRecipe(2);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When not in [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode), and when the `this` is not set by the call, `this` inside functions will default to the [global object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Global_object) ([`window`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window) in browsers).

```js
function f1() {
  return this;
}

console.log(f1() === window); // true
```

Also in browsers when not in strict mode, global variables (variables declared in the [global scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/global_scope)) declared with `var` are also created as members of the global object.

```js
var foo = "foobar";
console.log(foo === window.foo);
```

Because your `x` is declared as a global variable, it is also added as a member of the `window` object. Because your `setTimeout` callback does not explicitly set the `this` scope, it also defaults to the global object, and so it is possible you can access `x` via `this`.

If `x` would not have been declared in the global scope (or would've been declared in strict mode or with a [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let)/[`const`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) statement), you would not be able to access it:

```js
(function() {
  var x = 45;

  function getRecipe(recipe) {
    x = 35;
    return {
      displayRecipe: function(a) {
        //here we have access to x=35
        setTimeout(function() {
          //why do we have access to x=35 and to recipe here?
          console.log(this.x, a, recipe);
        }, 1500)
      }
    }

  }

  getRecipe("noodles").displayRecipe(2);
})();
```

Comment: so x=35 is declared in the global scope?

Comment: `var x = 45;` is declared in the global scope and thus a global variable. You change the value of this global variable to `35` inside your `getRecipe` function. (But changing the value does not change the scope of the variable.)

Answer (score 0):

You should put **let** before x=35

```
var x=45;
function getRecipe(recipe){
      let x=35;
      return{
         displayRecipe: function(a){
         //here we have access to x=35
            setTimeout(function(){
                //why do we have access to x=35 and to recipe here?
                console.log(this.x + a + recipe );
            },1500)
         }
      }

}

getRecipe("noodles").displayRecipe(2);
```